# How to sign URL Google Directions?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-directions-api

I have a function to retrieve Google Directions but I have a question about where to find the Google Crypto Key to sign my url. Where is this on the dashboard?

```
        public static void getDirections(Context context, String origin, String destination,
                                         final DirectionsListener listener)
                throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
            if (FrameworkUtils.isStringEmpty(origin) || FrameworkUtils.isStringEmpty(destination)) {
                return;
            }
            try {
                String url = String.format(GOOGLE_API_DIRECTIONS_URL, origin, destination,
                        ConfigurationManager.GOOGLE_CLIENT_KEY, KEY_TRAVEL_MODE_DRIVING);
                String signedUrl = UrlSigner.signURL(url);
                JsonRequest request = new JsonRequest(Method.GET, signedUrl, null, new JsonResponseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response, int resultCode) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray routesObject = response.getJSONArray(KEY_ROUTES);
                            JSONObject currentRoute = routesObject.getJSONObject(0);
                            JSONObject overViewPolyline = currentRoute.getJSONObject(KEY_OVERVIEW_POLYLINE);
                            String encodedPoints = overViewPolyline.getString(KEY_POINTS);
                            listener.onSuccess(decode(encodedPoints));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                }, new ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        // do nothing
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error, int resultCode) {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                }, 45);
  VolleyClient.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext()).addRequest(request);
            } catch (IOException | InvalidKeyException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Here is my signURL function

```
public static String signURL(String inputUrl) throws IOException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, URISyntaxException {
    URL url = new URL(inputUrl);
    String googleCryptoKey = ConfigurationManager.GOOGLE_CRYPTO_KEY;
    UrlSigner signer = new UrlSigner(googleCryptoKey);
    String request = signer.signRequest(url.getPath(), url.getQuery());
    return url.getProtocol() + "://" + url.getHost() + request;
}
```

I created this code from the example, but I am unable to figure what the Google Crypto Key should be?

The dashboard has

- API Key that I create
- from AIM & Admin I can see a Project ID and Project Number

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client ID and Cryptographic key are used in the Premium plan license. If you don't have a Premium plan license and use a Standard plan, you have to apply an API key in your request and digital signature is not necessary.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-api-key#standard-auth

So you can simplify your code to apply an API key instead of client ID and remove the part that creates a digital signature.

If you would like to protect your API key you should set IP restrictions in developer console. Client ID and digital signature is used to protect requests issued  by Premium plan users.